# Typescript changes variable value before executing methods

Tags: javascript, typescript

The code below executes the bottom line

`this.greetingWidgets[index].previous_position = this.greetingWidgets[index].current_position`

before running the methods called above it can anyone explain why?

```
 console.log('This is previous height & width ')

    previous_object_coordinates = this.old_coordinates(previous_position)
    console.log('Old coordinates')
    console.log(previous_object_coordinates)

    console.log('New coordinates')
    current_object_coordinates = this.new_coordinates(current_position)
    console.log(current_object_coordinates)

    console.log('Pop off coordinates')
    pop_coordinates = this.pop_coordinates(previous_object_coordinates, current_object_coordinates)
    console.log(pop_coordinates)

    console.log('Push in coordinates')
    push_coordinates = this.push_coordinates(current_object_coordinates, previous_object_coordinates)
    console.log(push_coordinates)


    this.greetingWidgets[index].previous_position = this.greetingWidgets[index].current_position
```

These are the methods called above.

```
  push_coordinates(arr1, arr2) {
    var arr3 = arr1.concat(arr2).filter(val => !(arr1.includes(val) && arr2.includes(val)))
    return (arr3)
  }

  pop_coordinates(previous_object_coordinates, current_object_coordinates) {
    var pop_coordinates = []
    pop_coordinates = previous_object_coordinates.filter(value => current_object_coordinates.includes(value))
    return (pop_coordinates)
  }

  new_coordinates(current_position) {
    var new_height_span = current_position.height
    var new_width_span = current_position.width
    var current_object_coordinates = []
    if (new_height_span) {
      for (var x = new_height_span; x > 0; x--) {
        for (var y = new_width_span; y > 0; y--) {
          var cordinates = Number(x + '.' + y)
          current_object_coordinates.push(cordinates)
        }

      }

      current_object_coordinates = [...new Set(current_object_coordinates)]


      for (var x = new_height_span; x > 0; x--) {
        for (var y = new_width_span; y > 0; y--) {
          var cordinates = Number(x + '.' + y)
          current_object_coordinates.push(cordinates)
        }

      }

      current_object_coordinates = [...new Set(current_object_coordinates)]

    }
    return (current_object_coordinates)

  }

  old_coordinates(previous_position) {
    var previous_position_cordinates = []
    var current_position = previous_position
    var old_height_span = previous_position.height
    var old_width_span = previous_position.width

    console.log('old position')
    if (old_height_span) {
      for (var x = old_height_span; x > 0; x--) {
        for (var y = old_width_span; y > 0; y--) {
          var cordinates = Number(x + '.' + y)
          previous_position_cordinates.push(cordinates)
        }

      }

      previous_position_cordinates = [...new Set(previous_position_cordinates)]


      for (var x = old_height_span; x > 0; x--) {
        for (var y = old_width_span; y > 0; y--) {
          var cordinates = Number(x + '.' + y)
          previous_position_cordinates.push(cordinates)
        }

      }

      previous_position_cordinates = [...new Set(previous_position_cordinates)]

    }

    return (previous_position_cordinates)

  }
```

Comment: Your conclusion that the code is running out of order seems very unlikely. What makes you think that's happening?

Comment: You might just be running into the fact that the UI for the Chrome console asynchronously renders the contents of objects. Since you're mutating the object being logged, you might just be seeing a race condition between when you log the object and when you inspect the object.

Comment: If you use a debugger such as the Chrome Dev Tools, you should be able to see the actual order of operations. The appearance of log messages is not directly related to the execution of your code statements and can come much later (if at all). Only the _internal order_ of log messages themselves should be reliable, if they are executed synchronously (which it looks like here). But a debugger will provide much better insight into actual execution.

Comment: The debugger shows that ```previous_object_coordinates``` is changing into ```current_object_coordinates``` value before running ```this.old_coordinates(previous_position)```